# VBScript syntax highlighting in VS2008?

Tags: vbscript, visual-studio-2008-sp1

ive got a few problems with my graphics driver and VS2010 so i wondered if someone could tell me how to get the syntax highlighting for VBScript on VS2008? I cant install IIS at the moment, but i have applied all the latest VS updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the script as a file with a ".vbs" extension and open this file in Visual Studio 2008, then syntax highlighting automatically becomes active.